# Distance to multiple geopoints- MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

Can we find distance to two or more geopoints in a query using `$geoNear` from query point?

```js
 Transport.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: first_route.origin.geocode,
            spherical: true,
            distanceField: "origin.distance",
            key: "route.origin.geocode"
        }
    },
 { $match: query },
```

I shall narrate the scenario. I have a collection of documents which contains list of bus services, so each document will contain details of a trip with start geopoint(A), end geopoint(B) and a linestring defines the path along with start time. So users can come and search for the bus by giving a start(AU) and end(BU) geopoint(using google api). What I am doing here to query a bus is that I buffer the geopoints selected by user using turfjs and check whether it intersects linestring in mongodb using `$geoIntersects`. Now i will get buses from A to B and B to A as result, i want filter out B to A from the result(user may search for a sub route in between actual bus route). For that I want find distance from starting point(A) of bus to "start point of user(AU)" and "end point selected by user(BU)", from these distances I can always make sure that A-AU is lesser than A-BU and thus filter out buses from B to A. Document is like below, I have removed a few coordinates to reduce length of data. I prefer logical suggestions also to overcome the issue.

```js
{
    "_id": "5bb21fe97c877c39e0bbc694",
    "route": {
        "origin": {
            "geocode": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    10.0601903,
                    76.6350827
                ]
            },
            "geocode_buffered": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [  ]
                ]
            },
            "place": "Kothamangalam, Kerala, India",
            "place_id": "ChIJqY5hYBLmBzsRB1zUid9GIqM"
        },
        "destination": {
            "geocode": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    9.9894229,
                    76.57897490000005
                ]
            },
            "geocode_buffered": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [ ]
                ]
            },
            "place": "Muvattupuzha, Kerala, India",
            "place_id": "ChIJ8_D2nYzdBzsR5WJwzP9sULQ"
        },
        "geocodes": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    10.06028,
                    76.63511000000001
                ],
                [
                    10.06042,
                    76.6346
                ],
                [
                    10.060490000000001,
                    76.63411
                ], 
                [
                    9.989220000000001,
                    76.58159
                ], 
                [
                    9.989450000000001,
                    76.5794
                ],
                [
                    9.98943,
                    76.57932000000001
                ],
                [
                    9.98935,
                    76.57905000000001
                ]
            ]
        },
        "route_index": 0,
        "route_name": "NH85" 
    },
    "access_type": "public",
    "type": "bus",
    "day_frequency": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7
    ],
    "duration_days": 0,
    "duration_hours": 0.23,
    "created_on": "2018-10-01T13:20:26.006Z",
    "title": "Rx100",
    "description": "Ls",
    "timings": [
        {
            "departure": "13:00",
            "destination": "13:23",
            "_id": "5bb21fe97c877c39e0bbc692",
            "trackings": []
        }
    ], 
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample data plz

Comment: matthPen, I have edited the question description.